# Embedding JavaScript in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I would just like to get a simple explanation as how embedding javascript in php works and why we need to echo it out. I just need to understand the concept of embedding javascript to php. I may just have been confusing myself but I just need someone to shed some light on this topic.

Comment: To which purpose do you want to embed javascript in PHP? The question is very vague?

Comment: js is just another string to php like any other.

Comment: Dragon, that is incorrect.

Comment: @Jason, share the wisdom

Comment: How are you getting the client side variable to the server Dragon? It is not accessible unless u pass via something like ajax.

Comment: You have to echo it out so it goes to the browser and can be run. But really, this is a bad idea. Separate your code.

Comment: that's the problem with a question like this there are a million interpretations, I  refer only  to "why we need to echo it out."

Comment: Echo out what? You can not "echo" a JavaScript variable from PHP with out getting it server side first.. Anyone else back me up here?

Comment: you can echo js just as you echo html css or anything else

Comment: ... Show a small example.. No you cant, not with out getting the js serverside.. When you set a js var, its client side...

Comment: `echo "<script>alert('its a bingo')</script>";`

Comment: Ok. Your correct with straight code, but once you set a js var, you cant do that. For some reason, I thought he meant a variable.

Comment: `echo "var foo = 'bar';"`

Comment: not sure why any one is bothering, it is just a bad question that should be closed.

Comment: Wow, he was asking for the "Concept" and ajax is part of that concept.. Nm...

Comment: Sorry for the "bad question", Im just trying to make sense of someone else's code. Im a junior developer for a credit card processing company and apparently its old code but thanks for all the answers everyone! have a great day!

Comment: btw it's my first time working with php that has html, css and javascript inside. I'm used to separating each one out and after seeing this code, my brain just got confused. =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's like any other programming language - you can use only THAT particular programming language to accomplish something. e.g.

```
<?php
$x = 42; // php variable assignment
alert($x); // javascript function call
```

This would never work. `alert() is a JS function which (usually) has no analog in PHP, therefore this would die with an undefined function error.

Since PHP can be embedded in other languages, and other languages can be "embedded" within PHP, you **HAVE** to have clear delimiters between the two, so the compilers can tell where one language ends and another starts. With php, that'd be accomplished by doing an "echo" of the JS code, or "breaking out" of PHP mode:

```
<?php
$x = 42;
?>
alert(<?php echo $x; ?>);
```

or

```
<?php
$x = 42;
echo 'alert(' . $x . ')';
```

What it boils down to is "context". If you're in PHP mode (e.g. within a `<?php ... ?>` block, you're writing PHP code, and any other language you use in there (html, JS) is just plain text as far as PHP is concerned.

If you're "out" of PHP mode, then you're in whatever language context the surrounding block is using.

```
<script>
   var x = 42;
   <?php // some php code here that causes output />
</script>
```

In the above case, your "context" is javascript - anything that the PHP causes to be output must be valid in the Javascript context it's embedded in.

so while

```
var x = <?php echo 42; ?>;
```

would work, because `42` is a valid bit of text to have in that particular spot, it would not be valid to have

```
var x = <?php echo '</script>'; ?>;
```

That would produce the non-sensical

```
var x = </script>;
```

Comment: Comprehensive... Nice!

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is client side, PHP is server side... Javascript can not be accessed by PHP.. You must use something like AJAX to pass back and fourth.. On the flip side, you can display PHP inside JavaScript.

```
<?
$a = "25";
?>
<script>
alert(<? echo $a ?>)
</script>
```

That works, but visa versa will not unless you use Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You should make all justifiable attempts to separate languages whenever possible.

Just the same as any other data PHP parses it will only output what you tell it to. So if you don't tell PHP to send the data to the browser it wont send it.

With regard to language separation there are loads of PHP template engines out there that work out of the box to do this for you. You just need to work within their framework.