# Insert javascript into PHP code

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, momentjs

Here is my code:

```
<script>
  var g = moment.tz.guess();
</script>

<?php
  $detectTimezone = new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');
?>
```

how can I replace `America/Los_Angeles` with var g?

Comment: You can't.  The PHP code executes entirely server-side before the page is even delivered to the client.  What are you actually trying to accomplish here?  There are *other things* you can do, depending on the actual goal.

Comment: You can't do this like that. PHP is processed before Javascript. (Php = server side, javascript = client side)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: I dont think you can unless you post it back to the server and get that posted variable from $_POST to set the value

Comment: Short answer - you can't. JS lives on the client, PHP on the server. The only way to communicate is via HTTP requests.

Comment: @David i'm trying to get the user's timezone which is a javascript variable because i can't do that with PHP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Embedding JavaScript in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29758791/embedding-javascript-in-php)

Comment: @johnjay22113: You can get that value client-side and then send it to server-side code, either with a form post (or page load of some kind) or with an AJAX request.  Do a Google search for things like "AJAX in PHP example" or similar, there are many examples available.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is You can't.

```
<?php
    $detectTimezone = new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');
?>
```

Above code executes on server side, and JavaScript runs on client side.
 The only way to do is using AJAX requests.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with all the comments saying that normally you cannot, just for the sake of completeness, there **are** workarounds indeed, like the accepted answer in here: [Access a JavaScript variable from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338942/access-a-javascript-variable-from-php).

I would not recommended it however for various reasons, most importantly because it makes things unclear and unnecessary complicated. As others said, it would help to state first *what* you are aiming to achieve?